# Absolute positioning in IE7 limiting width of div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, positioning, absolute

I'm working on drop down menus for this:
http://www.heroicdreams.com/wordpress/elderFlashSite.html

In every other browser it works great, but in IE7 the drop down widths are being limited by the size of the top link and it's margin. Is there a way to get IE to behave like all other browsers in that it will allow the drop down widths to extend beyond the original div size?

I'm using javascript to show/hide the menus, and a ul for each menu inside the same div as the origin link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a DOCTYPE to your page might help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

See (among others) [A List Apart: Fix Your Site With the Right DOCTYPE!](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/)